# what does `someVar` or single quote means in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have encountered this in apple documentation as well as the `NSObject` swift class:

```
func `self`() -> Self!

func conformsToProtocol(_ `aProtocol`: Protocol) -> Bool
```

I searched on the internet but I could not find what the single quote means in this context.
Does anybody here knows what it means or what it's called.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Swift [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html):

> To use a reserved word as an identifier, put a backtick (`) before and
>   after it. For example, class is not a valid identifier, but `class` is
>   valid. The backticks are not considered part of the identifier; `x`
>   and x have the same meaning.

```
``
```

Are called backticks.

In your example it seems the keyword `self` is being escaped so that the function can be named "self".

Comment: This seems like a "feature" that was created just to cause problems

Comment: @DuncanC it is in the NSObject swift file. It is an Apple thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got it now ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is really useful in closures where you want to use weak self.