# Use objective-c method in swift seems crossing keyword of swift language

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an objective-c method:

```
-(DeviceVar *)var:(NSString*)valid
```

In objective-c I simple use it as:

```
DeviceVar* rtc = [device var:@"rtc"];
```

But in swift I have a problem using this method:

```
let rtc = device.var("etc")
```

as var is a keyword I guess, so my question is how to make it work.

Comment: Can't you rename the method? That seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: @Losiowaty, it's an external library. Then I maybe will need decorate that object.

Comment: You can enclose keywords in backticks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315358/use-reserved-keyword-a-enum-case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551079/create-a-class-named-with-a-swift-used-name, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560281/what-does-somevar-or-single-quote-means-in-swift.

Comment: Yes, decoration seems like a way to go.

Comment: If you have access to the header files then you can give the methods a different Swift name with NS_SWIFT_NAME(...).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always enclose a reserved word in backticks if you need to 
use it as a method name (see for example
[Use reserved keyword a enum case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315358/use-reserved-keyword-a-enum-case)):

```
let rtc = device.`var`("etc")
```

If you have write access to the Objective-C header files then another
option is to define a different method name for Swift
(compare [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) in the
"Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C " reference):

```
-(DeviceVar *)var:(NSString*)valid NS_SWIFT_NAME(deviceVar(_:));
```

which can then be called from Swift as

```
let rtc = device.deviceVar("etc")
```